# Making certain questions appear on an html form through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to say thanks to the community. You've been a tremendous help so far.
Here's my latest question: I'm designing an online submission form, and one of the questions is a yes/no question with radio buttons. If the lead answers yes, I want a certain question to display. If they answer no, a different question will be displayed instead.

I looked at a few other answers and was able to scrape together some jQuerym but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is my javascript and a jsfiddle with the rest of my code.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes') {
            $('#ifyes').show();
        } else {
            $('#ifno').show();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrktj4kz/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: Your inputs don't have value.

Comment: To have a single selection when using radio, they should share the same name.

Comment: Well... You have plenty to get fixed before even thinking about the jQuery side of things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the fiddle, you should use

```
$('.ifyes').show();
```

and

```
$('.ifno').show();
```

instead.

You were using the id's of the input fields to show the element instead of the class of the wrapping div to which the `display: hidden;` style was applied.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code

HTML:

```
<li>
    <label for="coverage">K. Do you have current coverage?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" class="radio-toggle" data-target=".ifyes" data-target-group=".ifdiv" /> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="choice" class="radio-toggle" data-target=".ifno" data-target-group=".ifdiv" /> No
</li>

<li>
    <div class="ifyes ifdiv">
        <label for="ifyes">When does the policy expire?</label>
        <input type="text" id="ifyes" name="ifyes" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="ifno ifdiv">
        <label for="ifno">When do you need the policy to take effect?</label>
        <input type="text" id="ifno" name="ifno" value="" />
    </div>    
</li>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.radio-toggle').click(function() {
        $($(this).data('targetGroup')).hide();
        $($(this).data('target')).show();
    });
});
```

Obviously you need to call the jQuery library.
This is the complete and updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yrktj4kz/1/

Note that i'm using html data attribute to optimize the js code.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks for the help! I'm still new to forms (literally watched a tutorial yesterday) so I may have set it up incorrectly. Thanks.